# Value from submit button outside of $_POST

Tags: php, html, registration

I'm having an issue with my registration form and the script that validates it (checks it for blanks). Specifically, the value of the submit button in my registration form keeps popping up in the error message if there is one or more fields left blank in the registration form.

The following is an extract of the code I use to check for blanks in my registration form.

```
case "Register":
    //Checks for blank fields
    var_dump($_POST);
    foreach($_POST as $fields=>$rvalue)
    {
        if($rvalue=="Button")
                {       
                    continue;
                }
        //Checks if fields other than rdesc are empty
        if($fields!=="rdesc")
        {

            if(empty($rvalue))
            {
                //stores the empty field into an array
                $blanks[]=$rvalue;
            }
            else
            {
                $good_data[$fields]=strip_tags(trim($rvalue));
            }
        }
    }
    //If there are bank fields, the following code will execute.
    if(isset($blanks))
    {
        $errormsg="The fields below cannot be blank.Please fill all the fields: ";
        extract($good_data);
        $errormsg.="$rvalue ";
        include("Register.php");
        exit();
    }

include("LoginPage.php");

?>
```

This is my registration form

```
<?php
$regfields=array("remail"=>"Email","remail2"=>"Re-enter Email","rusername"=>"Username","rpassword"=>"Password","rpassword2"=>"Re-enter Password","rbiz"=>"BizName","rdesc"=>"Desc");
?>

<html>
<body>
<h3>Registration</h3>
<form action="Login.php" name="RegisterForm" method="post" >
<table border="0">

<?php

if(isset($errormsg))
{
    echo"$errormsg";
}

foreach($regfields as $field=>$value)
{

    if($field=="rdesc")
    {
        echo"<tr>";
        echo"<td>";
        echo"<label for='$field'>$value: </label>";
        echo"</td>";
        echo"<td>";
        echo"<input type='text' name='$field' size='300' maxlength='300' style='width:400px;height:100px; \n' /></td></tr>";
        echo"<tr>";
        echo"<td>";
This Register value keeps showing up--->echo"<input type='submit' name='Button' value='Register'/>";
        echo"</td>";
        echo"<tr>";
    }
    else if($field=="remail"||$field=="remail2")
    {
        echo"<tr>";
        echo"<td>";
        echo"<label for='$field'>$value: </label>";
        echo"</td>";
        echo"<td>";
        echo"<input type='text' name='$field' size='40' maxlength='50' /></td></tr>";

    }
    else if($field=="rpassword"||$field=="rpassword2")
    {
        echo"<tr>";
        echo"<td>";
        echo"<label for='$field'>$value: </label>";
        echo"</td>";
        echo"<td>";
        echo"<input type='password' name='$field' size='40' maxlength='50' /></td></tr>";

    }
    else
    {
        echo"<tr>";
        echo"<td>";
        echo"<label for=$field>$value: </label>";
        echo"</td>";
        echo"<td>";
        echo"<input type='text' name='$field' size='40' maxlength='50'/>";
        echo"</td>";
        echo"</tr>";
    }
}

?>
```

I've tried using a var dump to see what's inside `$_POST`, and I got:

```
array(8) { ["remail"]=> string(5) "Email" ["remail2"]=> string(5) "Email" ["rusername"]=> string(0) "" ["rpassword"]=> string(6) "Testpw" ["rpassword2"]=> string(6) "Testpw" ["rbiz"]=> string(8) "Testname" ["rdesc"]=> string(8) "TestDesc" ["Button"]=> string(8) "Register" } **Register***<---This is the register value i was talking about that is outside of the array.
```

and the error message

> The fields below cannot be blank.Please fill all the fields: Register

However, when I fill up the registration form without any blanks, a var dump gives me:

```
array(8) { ["remail"]=> string(5) "Email" ["remail2"]=> string(5) "Email" ["rusername"]=> string(8) "TestUser" ["rpassword"]=> string(6) "Testpw" ["rpassword2"]=> string(6) "Testpw" ["rbiz"]=> string(8) "Testname" ["rdesc"]=> string(8) "TestDesc" ["Button"]=> string(8) "Register" }
```

where the "Register" that was outside the array is gone.

I've added the code

```
if($rvalue=="Button")
{       
    continue;
}
```

to try and skip the value "Register" of the submit button but it doesn't seem to be working.

Could someone tell me what i can do to remove the "Register" value from the error message so that it would correctly display the fields that were left blank?

EDIT:These are the code in it's entirety

Login.php

session_start();

switch ($_POST["Button"])
{
    case "Login":
        include("cxn.inc");
        $cxn=mysqli_connect($host,$user,$pw,$db) or die("Can't connect to database");
        $query="SELECT * FROM Users WHERE username='$_POST[lusername]'";
        $result=mysqli_query($cxn,$query) or die (" Cant find Username from Users table");
        $num=mysqli_num_rows($result);

```
        if($num>0)//Username is found
        {
            $query="SELECT * FROM Users WHERE Password='$_POST[lpassword]'";
            $result2=mysqli_query($cxn,$query)or die("Cant find Password");
            $num2=mysqli_num_rows($result2);
            if($num2>0)//Password is found
            {
                $_SESSION['Auth']="Yes";
                $_SESSION['Type']="Admin";
                header("Location:AdminMain.php");
            }
            else
            {
                echo"Invalid Username and/or Password";
            }

        }
        elseif($num==0)//Executes when Username not found in Users table
        {
            $query="SELECT * FROM SubUsers WHERE Username='$_POST[lusername]'";
            $result3=mysqli_query($cxn,$query) or die(" Cant find Username from SubUsers table");
            $num3=mysqli_num_rows($result3);
            if($num3>0)//Username is found
            {
                $query="SELECT * FROM SubUsers WHERE Password='$_POST[lpassword]'";
                $result4=mysqli_query($cxn,$query);
                $num4=mysqli_num_rows($result4);
                if($num4>0)//Password is found
                {
                    $_SESSION['Auth']="Yes";
                    $_SESSION['Type']="Sub";
                    header("Location:SubMain.php");
                }
                else
                {
                    echo"Cant find Password";
                }
            }
            else
            {
                echo"Username and/or Password is non-existent";
            }
        }
        else
        {
            echo"Invalid Username and/or Password entered";
        }


    break;

case "Register":
    //Checks for blank fields
    var_dump($_POST);
    foreach($_POST as $fields=>$rvalue)
    {
        if($fields=="Button"&& $rvalue == "Register")
                {       
                    continue;
                }
        //Checks if fields other than rdesc are empty
        if($fields!=="rdesc")
        {

            if(!empty($rvalue))
            {
                //stores the empty field into an array
                $blanks[]=$fields;
            }
            else
            {
                $good_data[$fields]=strip_tags(trim($rvalue));
            }
        }
    }

    if(!empty($blanks))
    {
        $errormsg="The fields below cannot be blank.Please fill all the fields: ";
        extract($good_data);
        $errormsg.="$rvalue ";
        include("Register.php");
        exit();
    }
```

}

include("LoginPage.php");

?>

Comment: check the difference between yours & mine.   `if($rvalue=="Button"&& $rvalue == "Register")` the first condition should be `$fields == "Button"`, not `$rvalue == "Button"`.

Comment: Noting in your full posted code now, that this is vulnerable to SQL injection.  At a minimum, you must call `mysql_real_escape_string()` on your query inputs (`$_POST['lusername']`, for example)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are testing in your loop for a field *value* of `Button`, but in fact it is the field *name* you need to test.  The `<input type="submit">` sends its value of `Register`, and that's the value you see in your `print_r()`.

```
// Skip the submit button by name, not value
if($fields == "Button")
{       
   continue;
}
```

If you had more submit inputs named `Button`, you might also test the value since only the one which was clicked would be submitted to PHP in the `$_POST`, though it isn't necessary here.

```
if($fields == "Button" && $rvalue == "Register")
{       
   continue;
}
```

Next, if you have declared the array `$blanks` explicitly as:

```
$blanks = array();
```

... rather than allowing it to be implicitly declared on the first blank field by

```
if(empty($rvalue))
{
    //stores the empty field into an array
    $blanks[]=$rvalue;
}
```

... then your later check for `isset($blanks)` will always be `true`, and the *last* element iterated in the `foreach` will be appended to the error message. In this case, that happens to be `Register`, even though it was skipped in the body of the loop.

Instead, check for the empty array via `empty()`.

```
if (!empty($blanks)) 
{
   $errormsg="The fields below cannot be blank.Please fill all the fields: ";
   // etc...
}
```

Instead of using `$rvalue` in the error message (which will always hold the *last* array element from the loop, no matter where it failed), implode the contents of `$blanks`.

```
if (!empty($blanks)) 
{
   $errormsg = "The fields below cannot be blank.Please fill all the fields: ";
   $errormsg .= implode(", ", $blanks);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your input Michael, by testing both the name and value of the submit input "Button" the "Register" value that was lying outside of the $_POST array was missing.However, the error message still reads
"The fields below cannot be blank.Please fill all the fields: Register" where the "Register value is somehow still $rvalue instead of the fields which were left empty". Shouldn't $rvalue no longer be "Register" since i'm skipping the Submit button?

Comment: @Ken Do you declare the array `$blanks` somewhere we can't see, or is it declared implicitly by `$blanks[] = $rvalue`? If it is declared, it will be `isset()`, and your last block will always execute.  Use `if (!empty($blanks))` instead.

Comment: @Ken I just looked at your updated code, and you have incorrectly checked the name & value.  `if($rvalue=="Button"&& $rvalue == "Register")` should have been  if($fields=="Button"&& $rvalue == "Register")` -- you have used `$rvalue` for both conditions.

Comment: @ Michael Berkowski I've changed it back to if($fields=="Button" &&$rvalue=="Register") Though it still isn't working and "Register" is still popping up. I'll keep working on it and ill post any solutions i find here. Thanks for your input thus far!

Comment: @Ken If `$blanks` is nonempty (as it fails the `!empty()` check), might I suggest `print_r($blanks)` to see what's actually in there?  And see edit about about using its contents in the error messgge.

Answer (score 1):

try

```
if($fields=="Button")
{       
    continue;
}
```

$rvalue is the value and you need the key ;)

Answer (score 1):

First logical problem here:

```
if(empty($rvalue))
        {
            //stores the empty field into an array
            $blanks[]=$rvalue;
        }
```

you're storing emptiness into `$blanks[]`:P You meant to store `$fields`

Second problem here:
`$errormsg.="$rvalue ";` At the end of all the iterations of the `foreach($_POST as $fields=>$rvalue)`, `$rvalue` will hold the value of the last element of $_POST, which in this case happens to be `rdesc`. Hence the value of the submit button is popping up everytime.

What you *need* to do is something like this:

```
foreach($blanks as $field_left_blank)
{
 $errormsg.="$field_left_blank ,";
}
```